# How to add ability to show also decimal parts to a star review?

Tags: html, css

I have this code for review stars:

```
<p>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
    123 reviews of clientes
</p>

<style type="text/css">
  .checked {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

The problem is that it shows only whole stars. Whereas I need decimals as well, or at least halfs.

I've tried

```
.checked_half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

That didn't work.

How can I do this? I want to a simple solution. It's static, not dynamic, javascript isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

There's an [icon for a 'half-star'](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/star-half-o) in fontawesome which you are using here.

You can simply replace the class, `fa-star` with `fa-star-half-o` and use the same to change the colour in CSS like so:

```css
.fa-star {
  color: red;
}

.fa-star-half-o {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-half-o"></span> 123 reviews of clientes
</p>
```